# Debugging ASP.NET MVC framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, debugging

What do I have to do in order to be able to step into ASP.NET MVC framework functions when debugging my own ASP.NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2008? I've currently installed the framework via the [MSI installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en#filelist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, but since the debugger still stepped over the MVC code for some unknown reason, I simply downloaded the MVC source, added it as a project to my solution and referenced it from there. Now I can perfectly debug the framework.

Answer (score 2):

You could download [the source](http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet) from Codeplex, and add the folder you extract it to to Visual Studio's search path. (In Tools->Options->Debugger, I think)

Answer (score 1):

asp.net mvc is now released - once you install the vs2008 templates ( which is part of the install) http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en you should not have to do anything to debug. 
make sure that you have references to the System.web.mvc and routing dlls.
also check the web config file for the debugging attribute and also check that (if running under IIS) then IIS has debugging enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this blog post: **[Using the ASP.NET MVC source code to debug your app](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/02/03/using-the-aspnet-mvc-source-code-to-debug-your-app/)** , by Steve Sanders.

It works as expected/wanted.